# How to generate rows for table Order_details, for each row in the Order_header table?

Tags: sql, oracle, random

I have two tables. Order_header and Order_detail. For each row in the Order_header table, I want to generate 1 or more Order_detail rows and insert them into the Order_detail table. The number of detail rows for each header row is random, up to the number in the constant max_detailrows. How to proceed with the generate rows for Order_detail table?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Post an example, include the table details, insert statements and your desired output. And explain the rules to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_random.htm#ARPLS67507) function, to generate random value.
Use this in [hierarchical query](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535?start=0&tstart=0) to generate rows for each row in your Order_Header table.

Schema Setup:

```
create table order_header(
  order_id number,
  order_desc varchar2(10)
  );

insert into order_header values(1,'lorem');
insert into order_header values(2,'ewroc');
insert into order_header values(3,'tdsfg');

commit;

create table order_details(
  order_id number,
  order_detail_nr number,
  order_detail_desc varchar2(20)
  );
```

Query:

```
insert into order_details
select 
    order_id,
    level,
    order_desc || '_' || level
from order_header
connect by level <= dbms_random.value(1,7)  --max number of rows needed should be given here.
and prior order_id = order_id
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

Output:

```
select * from order_details
order by 1,2;

  ORDER_ID ORDER_DETAIL_NR ORDER_DETAIL_DESC
---------- --------------- ------------------
         1               1 lorem_1
         1               2 lorem_2
         1               3 lorem_3
         2               1 ewroc_1
         2               2 ewroc_2
         2               3 ewroc_3
         2               4 ewroc_4
         3               1 tdsfg_1
```